# AngularJS Accessing Aliased Controller Attribute From Directive

Tags: angularjs

OK this is a contrived example, but...

Say I have a controller like this:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function() {
    this.testString;
    this.otherString;
});
```

And I have a template like this:

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl as test'>
    <input demo type='text' ng-model='test.testString'>
    {{test.otherString}}
</div>
```

And then I have a directive like this:

```
app.directive('demo', function() {
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal) {

                /* How do I get otherString without knowing the controller alias?
                   This works but is not good practice */
                scope.test.otherString = newVal + ' is cool!';

                /* This doesn't work, but would if the property was in scope 
                   instead of the controller */
                scope[attrs.demo] = newVal + ' is cool!';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How do I get otherString without knowing the controller alias? I could just break apart attrs.ngModel to get it, but is there an 'angular' way to get the property?

**EDIT**

While this example didn't exactly reflect the issues I was having with my real scenario, I did find out how to get the controller's property in the link function, allowing me to update the model:

```
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            var otherString = scope.$eval(attrs.demo);              

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal) {
                otherString = newVal + ' is cool!';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Directives are really all about DOM manipulation and shouldn't be directly tied to a controller. I realized this is a contrived example but it seems like your directive should really just be a child controller since it is more concerned with scope than the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A directive should have zero knowledge of anything outside of itself. If the directive depends on an outside controller having defined some arbitrary property, things will break very easily.

Defining a "scope" property on the directive lets you expose an explicit API for binding data to the directive.

```
myModule.directive('demo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      demoString: '=demo',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // You can access demoString here, or in a directive controller.
      console.log(scope.demoString);
    }        
  };
});
```

And the template

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl as test'>
    <input demo="test.otherString" ng-model='test.testString'>
    {{test.otherString}}
</div>
```

This isn't the *only* way to facilitate passing data or setting up bindings to a directive, but it is the most common way and should cover the majority of use-cases.

Comment: Thanks, jelbourn. I had explored this option but unfortunately my test case doesn't exactly match what I'm trying to do, which is to extend functionality on an existing directive that declares its own isolated scope- so when I try to do this in my directive it throws an error. I'll mark your answer correct, but any idea on what to do in the case of my real-life scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extend functionality on an existing directive". Adding behavior at run-time based on some program state or user action?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I figured out what I can do though- will update OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to be more angular-like I would just use the $scope in the controller and pass that to the directive like so:

```
app.directive('demo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {strings: '='},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        scope.$watch('strings.test', function(newVal) {

            /* How do I get otherString without knowing the controller alias? */
            scope.strings.other = newVal + ' is cool!';

        });
    }
}
});
```

then in the html:

```
   <div ng-controller='TestCtrl as test'>
      <input demo type='text' strings="strings" ng-model="strings.test" />
      {{strings.other}}
   </div>
```

In the controller you would assign:

```
$scope.strings = {
    test: '',
    other: ''
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a job for a directive though. You could easily get a way with doing this in a controller. But as another user commented, it is really bad practice to pass controllers to directives. Pass it through the scope or use a service.